# Error: "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table" although primary key is included

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a comments app for a Django project whereby each record can have a number of comments attached to it. However, when I try to migrate my model, I get the following error:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "user_info"

What am I doing wrong?

Currently my models look like this:

users/models.py

```py
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    #Includes a number of other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_info'
        ordering = ['id']
```

comments/models.py

```py
from users.models import UserInfo

class Comments(models.Model):
    patient_record = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: models are automatically given an id field, so why are you explicitly defining one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `unique=True` to your field and you should be good to go.

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    #Includes a number of other fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_info'
        ordering = ['id']
```

The primary key needs to be unique to work. If not, you can simply have made two `UserInfo` entries with the same `id`, rendering the PK useless. On a separate note, why are you using your own `id` field instead of the one already provided by Django?

Comment: Thank you, on the point of why I'm not using an id field, this model is created from an external database using inspectdb and the model is essentially untouched from what was generated. If you don't mind me asking, what would be the benefit to me using an ID field?

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Django models automatically have a field called `id` which is essentially the same thing that you've created here (except it's an auto increment int). It is also a unique primary key. You can always use both, by the way! You can change the name of your current `id` field to `old_id` and not use it as a primary key. This will allow you to query both the old IDs and the new IDs if you ever have a use for that.